# XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document\nLine: 1\n

Tags: magento2

[image: Api's stopped working suddenly.and showing this error.I have checked the file xml syntax was allright.Can someine help me please.]

Api's stopped working suddenly, and it's showing this error.

I have checked the file XML syntax was correct.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you please update webapi.xml? Did you changed code from webapi.xml from vendor folder?

Comment: No I didn't changed any code

Comment: This error is because of `<?xml` declaration should be in top of the file. i.e: 1st line. Explain briefly like what is resource you trying to access via API?

Comment: Thankyou.solved.

Comment: welcome .....:-)